# Python Querying on database with where clause

Tags: python, sql, database, date, pyodbc

I am new to Python and want to understand the syntax for connecting to MS sql database.
Have successfully created the connection but want to select a conditional data.
Please suggest how can below be done in python:

```
import pyodbc as odbc
cursor.execute("SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM Data where date between sysdate and (sysdate-1) ;")
```

I have already assigned Start and end as :

```
End = dt.datetime.today()
Start = End - dt.timedelta(days=1)
```

How can this be incorporated in the query above?? 
Also, it would be really helpful if you could point me to some documentation where other such related things might be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [pyodbc documentation for .execute](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters), you can use `?` as parameter placeholders in your SQL command text and pass the parameter values to `.execute` like so:

```python
End = dt.datetime.today()
Start = End - dt.timedelta(days=1)
sql = "SELECT [Col1],[Col2] FROM [Data] WHERE [date] BETWEEN ? AND ?"
cursor.execute(sql, Start, End)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: does the statement also work as below:    cursor.execute( "SELECT [Col1],[Col2] FROM [Data] WHERE [date] >= ? AND [date] < ?",Start,End)

Comment: I am getting the error when executing the data: Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional feature not implemented (0) (SQLBindParameter)')

Answer (score 0):

I believe Gord's answer is the correct one but in case this is useful, you can also prepare dynamically you SQL statement within your Python code and provide the SQL statement already updated with the parameters to your cursor.

This should solve your error:

> Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional
>   feature not implemented (0) (SQLBindParameter)')

```
end = dt.datetime.today()
start = End - dt.timedelta(days=1)
sql = "SELECT [Col1],[Col2] FROM [Data] WHERE [date] BETWEEN '{}' AND '{}'".format(start, end)
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Start = StringVar()
End = StringVar()

End = dt.datetime.today()
Start = End - dt.timedelta(days=1)

sql = "SELECT [Col1],[Col2] FROM [Data] WHERE [date] BETWEEN ? AND ?"
cursor.execute(sql, Start, End)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```